# Reactive Synchronization

Tags: c#, synchronization, system.reactive, scheduler, blockingcollection

I have a producer which produces some events every 100 ms and I have a consumer which simply outputs those values but when some condition is satisfied (value == 3) it has to download some data from web and continue with the next value.

Currently when that condition is satisfied it executes the download code in another thread and the consumer keeps pulling the next values while download is in progress.
What I want is to synchronize the events so that the pulling of the 4th event to happen not right away but after the download is finished which is after the 3rd event.

The `Download: 45717; Read: 3`event should come after `Read: 2` event.

```
Read: 0
Read: 1
Read: 2
Read: 4
Read: 5
Read: 6
Read: 7
Read: 8
Download: 45717; Read: 3
Read: 9
Read: 10
Read: 11
Read: 12
```

I tried to add `CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance` scheduler to `GetStringAsync("...").ToObservable(scheduler)` but couldn't make it work the way I want.

**When I replace the `ProperDownload` with `FakeDownload` I get the result I want.**

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();

            var publisher = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Select(i => (int) i)
                                      .Do(i => { queue.Add(i, cancellationTokenSource.Token); });

            const int targetValue = 3;

            var consumer = Observable.Defer(() => queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationTokenSource.Token).ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default))
                                     .SelectMany(value => value == targetValue
                                                              ? ProperDownload(value)
                                                              : Observable.Return(value, CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance)
                                                                          .Do(v => { Console.WriteLine($"Read: {v}"); }));

            using (publisher.Merge(consumer).Subscribe())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribe?");
                Console.ReadKey();

                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Copy the results.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IObservable<int> ProperDownload(int value)
        {
            return Observable.Using(() => new HttpClient(), client => client.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com").ToObservable())
                             .Select(response => response.Length)
                             .Do(responseLength => { Console.WriteLine($"Download: {responseLength}; Read: {value}"); });
        }

        private static IObservable<int> FakeDownload(int value)
        {
            return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance).Select(i => (int) i)
                             .Do(responseLength => { Console.WriteLine($"Download: {responseLength}; Read: {value}"); });
        }
    }
}
```